# how to use php to read one specific line from a text file that occurs after a tag

Tags: php, text-files

I am trying to read data from a plain text file from an industrial machine recipe.  The file is generated automatically by the tool.  I want to access a specific parameter in a specific section of the file.

The parameter is called "LightSrcRef_NominalGL"  The problem is that there are some number of parameters named as such in the file.  I specifically want the first one, and only the one, that occurs after the tag "[Scan2d]"

Note that the parameter I need does not always show on the same line number and that [Scan2d] does not always show up in the same place, but I need the parameter in the Scan2d section.  It also appears that the LightSrcRef_NominalGL parameter is not always the same number of lines after [Scan2d].

What I had hoped was to read the file line by line.  When I get to [Scan2d], set a flag, then when I get to the parameter, set my variable, then get out.

This is not happening.  Instead, it is taking the first LightSrcRef_NominalGL in the file.

We have similar recipe analyzers, but this is the first one with this unique recipe structure.  I have looked for a way to read the file in differently, but none produce different results.

When I print the actual line, it shows that the text file is reading it line by line.  I do not understand why it is not behaving as expected.

Here is example of text file.  In this case it is at the end of the file.  In others, there will be another section after.  I had to add an extra carriage return in the text file because this was not displaying them as separate lines.  They are being read in by lines because if I have it print $line, it shows exactly one line.

[Scan2d]

CameraTypeName=2D

FocusPosAboveChuck=-2.59084174217116

Mag=5

CameraName=HighMag

DifRingPos=2

Gamma=-1

LightSrcDif_ColorFilter=Gray

LightSrcDif_NominalGL=0

LightSrcRef_ColorFilter=Cyan

LightSrcRef_NominalGL=195.424629214628

```php
$catcher = 0;  //used to verify the parameter only in scan2d section
                            $lines = file($dir.$default_directory."/".$current_recipe_file);

                            foreach($lines as $line)
                            {   $line_count ++;
                                if(preg_match("/[Scan2d]\b/i", $line))
                                {
                                    $catcher = $line_count; //used to only catch the parameter in the Scan2D section
                                }   
                                if(preg_match("/\bLightSrcRef_NominalGL=\b/i", $line))
                                {  
                                    $illumination_split_temp1 = preg_split("/\=/", $line);
                                    $recipe_illum = $illumination_split_temp1[1];

                                    if ($catcher >0) 
                                    {print $line . "   ". $catcher .  "<br>"; 
                                        $Tool_Ins150_Stats->Add_Recipe_Tag("Illumination Level", $recipe_illum);
                                        $catcher= 0;
                                        break;
                                    }   

                                }
                            }
```

It is taking the first LightSrcRef_NominalGL in the file, not the one after Scan2d.

Comment: Use capture groups while `preg_match` If you want more help better to show some part of the text file, and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

If the tags you are looking for are at the start of the lines in the file this can be made even simpler. I changed what you had slightly so that when the section you are interested in is found the `foreach` goes to the next record.

```
$catcher = 0;
foreach($lines as $line) {
    if(preg_match("/[Scan2d]\b/i", $line)) {
        $catcher = 1;
        continue;
    }   
    if(preg_match("/\bLightSrcRef_NominalGL=\b/i", $line)) {  

        if (!$catcher) {
            continue;  // we haven't found the right section yet
        }
        $illumination_split_temp1 = preg_split("/\=/", $line);
        $recipe_illum = $illumination_split_temp1[1];
        print $line . "   ". $catcher .  "<br>"; 
        $Tool_Ins150_Stats->Add_Recipe_Tag("Illumination Level", $recipe_illum);
        $catcher= 0;
        break;
        }
}
```

Comment: This returns nothing.  The print statement never executes.  I would expect this logic to work, as it is similar to what I was trying to achieve.  Thank you for answering.

Comment: all right, working with this logic has something that works mostly.  I have one specific file where it is failing, and can't see anything different about that file compared to the others.  That said, adding a counter to the second part, it is hitting that "LightSrcRef_NominalGL=" match every time in the file.  Shouldn't it only reach that once because of the "continue" above it? 

Thanks again.  Progress is appreciated.

Comment: Bah, I spoke to soon.  It is taking the LAST value instead of the first.  The If (!$catcher) continue doesn't seem to break out of the loop.  If I print each $line it shows this.

Comment: The `if (!$catcher)` is not designed to stop the `foreach`, it is there to move on to the next line (go back to the foreach and the next line).

Answer (score 0):

```php
    $lines = file($dir.$default_directory."/".$current_recipe_file);
    $catcher = 0;  //used to verify the parameter only in scan2d section
    foreach($lines as $line)
        {   
            if(preg_match("/\[Scan2d]/", $line))
            {
                $catcher = 1; //used to only catch the parameter in the Scan2D section
            }
            if (!$catcher)
            {   
                continue;  // haven't found the right one yet, skip the rest                
            }
            else 
            {   
                if(preg_match("/LightSrcRef_NominalGL=/", $line)) 
                {   
                    $illumination_split_temp1 = preg_split("/\=/", $line);
                    $recipe_illum = $illumination_split_temp1[1];
                    $Tool_Ins150_Stats->Add_Recipe_Tag("Illumination Level", $recipe_illum);
                    $catcher = 0; 
                    continue;
                }
            }   
        }
```

This worked, but many thanks to Dave who certainly put me on the right track!!  The use of Else worked when I still do not fully understand why the second preg_match was executing if $catcher was not set (and it wasn't, I printed it to be sure).

Answer (score 0):

The sample your provided seems to be a file in [`ini` format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file). If this is really the case, there is a very simple solution using the [`parse_ini_file` function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php)

```php
<?php

$values = parse_ini_file('sample.txt', true, INI_SCANNER_TYPED);
echo "The value is " . $values["Scan2d"]["LightSrcRef_NominalGL"] . "\n";
```

I tried against this `sample.txt` file

```
[test]
LightSrcRef_NominalGL=0

[Scan2d]
CameraTypeName=2D
FocusPosAboveChuck=-2.59084174217116
Mag=5
CameraName=HighMag
DifRingPos=2
Gamma=-1
LightSrcDif_ColorFilter=Gray
LightSrcDif_NominalGL=0
LightSrcRef_ColorFilter=Cyan
LightSrcRef_NominalGL=195.424629214628

[test2]
LightSrcRef_NominalGL=1
```

And the result is:

```
The value is 195.42462921463
```

Of course, this will work only if your entire file respects the `ini` format as in your sample data.